# Checkbox: how to cross out text one by one and not altogether Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have following problem, I have a Checkbox list, and if I click on the checkbox all parts that the list contains get crossed out, but I want that the specific box crosses out the specific text line.This is how it looks like. If I press any box, all my text gets crossed out.
[image]

Here is the (Hopefully)relevant code

```
                body: SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: info.expandedValueData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text(info.expandedValueData[index].title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                decoration: info.completed
                                    ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                    : null)),
                        value: info.completed,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
// Here you toggle the checked item state
                            infos.firstWhere(
                                    (currentInfo) => info == currentInfo)
                              ..completed = value;
                          });
                        });
                  }),
            ),
```

Edit so do I need to add the Boolean like this?:

```
expandedValue(id: 2, completed: false, title: "funktionierende Elektrik"),
  expandedValue(id: 3, completed: false, title: "Sitze"),
  expandedValue(id: 4, completed: false, title: "Rest"),
```

I changed it like that & in the previous code I edited the info.completed part out to info.expandedValueData[index].completed, after that I got the error "Boolean expression must not be null", couldn't figure out how to solve this problem:

```
                        return CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text(info.expandedValueData[index].title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                decoration:
                                    info.expandedValueData[index].completed
                                        ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                        : null)),
                        value: info.expandedValueData[index].completed,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
// Here you toggle the checked item state
                            infos.firstWhere(
                                (currentInfo) => info == currentInfo)
                              ..expandedValueData[index].completed = value;
                          });
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what can be seen in the code you provided, I'd say that your problem is that you have only one `completed` variable. You should have a `completed` variable for every element in your list.
Instead of storing the boolean variable that marks a `CheckboxListTile` as completed in `info.completed` it should be stored for every element in `info.expandedValueData[index].completed`.

Comment: I stored it now for every element & changed the info.completed part out with info.expandedValueData[index].completed, after that I got the error  "boolean expression must not be null", I posted the edited code above, where do I have my mistake, didn't quite succeed in resolving this mistake.

Comment: Don't know why, restarted the application new and it worked, code should be correct, I think that there was something that was fixed with debugging